# Can java handle exceptions caused by MS SQL Server RAISEERROR command?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, exception, raiserror

well unfortunately I've been pushed to a situation which makes me using java to execute some stored procedures in MS SQL Server. I am using the RAISEERROR command in the SPs when an exception occurs. The problem is that java seems to be unable to catch these exceptions. 
My sample SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test] 
    @fname nchar(30),
    @lname nchar(30)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        IF (@fname) = 'something'
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'First name is not valid!',16,1, N'number', 5);
            RETURN
        END
        Insert into [users] (
            [id]
          ,[fname]
          ,[lname]
          )
       Values
        (
            '1',
            @fname,
            @lname
        )
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH   
END
```

My Java code:

```
try {
                // Establish the connection.
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                    //------- Call a sp
                    String SPsql="EXEC sp_test ?,?"; //String SPsql="EXEC <sp_test> ?,?";
                    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(SPsql);
                    ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
                    ps.setQueryTimeout(20);
                    ps.setString(1, "something");
                    ps.setString(2, "12346");
                    //ps.setString(parameterIndex, x)
                   ps.execute();

                    }
            }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The SP gets executed normally but no exception is caught in java!

So, can java handle these kind of exceptions? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You are swallowing the exception in the T-SQL code. Re-raise from the `BEGIN CATCH ... END CATCH` block

Answer (score 2):

Statement `RAISERROR ..` is not executed due to `nchar` (fixed length string). Change it to `nvarchar`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test] 
    @fname nvarchar(30),
    @lname nvarchar(30)
AS
```

Comment: well thank you for your reply, but the issue wasn't that. What you said was useful anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys my bad, I forgot to fill the catch part in the SP, so putting RAISEERROR there solved my issue:

```
.
.
.
    BEGIN CATCH
        RAISERROR (N'ERROR OCCURED!!! %s %d.', 16, 1, N'number', 5); 
    END CATCH
```